# Count Distinct Content in XPath 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-1.0

Given the following XML

```
<Address>
 <CountryName>France</CountryName>
</Address>
...
<Address>
 <CountryName>Germany</CountryName>
</Address>
...
<Address>
 <CountryName>Spain</CountryName>
</Address>
```

How can I count the number of distinct countries using XPath 1.0?

The list of addresses is very long and contains many distinct countries so I want to avoid having to express each one specifically.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the count of all the `CountryName` elements who's value is not the same value as the `CountryName` elements that are children of the current `CountryName` element's parent's following-siblings that are `Address` elements:

```
count(//Address/CountryName[not(.=../following-sibling::Address/CountryName)])
```

Comment: You are assuming records are sorted by CountryName, I think.

Comment: No, sort order does not matter.

Comment: Nice one!  We can avoid assuming that all Address elements are siblings by evaluating (on the root element) `count(./descendant::CountryName[not( . = preceding::CountryName)])` (@michael.hor257k - no, sorted input would be required only if we  added [1] to the following-sibling expression.)

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen Yes, I got that when told the first time, thank you. I just thought that it was well established that this method is "very inefficient" (quoting from the above article), so I didn't think anyone would suggest it - esp. as OP states that "the list of addresses is very long".

Comment: Apologies; no offense intended.  As for the efficiency -- sometimes it matters.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen None taken.

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen your answer ended up being perfect - I neglected to imply in my OP that the Addresses were indeed not siblings.  Thank you for the suggestion!